# I can't get eclipse to work

Tags: java, eclipse, installation

I'm trying to get Eclipse to work on my PC.  I've tried a few times to install it. It worked the first time but, I got exit code 13.  I added the -vm argument with the path to eclipse.ini but, after that it said "no java virtual machine was found".  I deleted all JRE JDK and Eclipse files and tried to install everything again but, now I can't get Eclipse. Here is the log:

```
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_121-b13
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.neon
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.6.0.v20161125-0947, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.6.0.v20161128-0928, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.6.0.v20161019-0656, build=2790, branch=33010448bcf5775ec23e485876cbb07a0340b9b5
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Neon))
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Offline = false
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Mirrors = true
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Resolving 23 requirements from 3 repositories to C:\Users\Kai\eclipse\java-neon2\eclipse
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement epp.package.java [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.6.0,4.7.0)
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.mylyn.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.recommenders.snipmatch.rcp.feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Requirement org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000
[2017-02-12 11:55:53] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2017-02-12 11:55:56] Calculating requirements and dependencies.
[2017-02-12 11:55:56] Computing prerequisite plan
[2017-02-12 11:55:57] Collecting 3 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000
[2017-02-12 11:55:57] Downloading org.eclipse.platform_root
[2017-02-12 11:55:57] Downloading org.eclipse.platform.ide.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2017-02-12 11:55:57] Downloading org.eclipse.rcp_root
[2017-02-12 11:55:57] Collected 3 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/201612211000 in 0.321s
[2017-02-12 11:55:57] Collecting 1 artifacts from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon
[2017-02-12 11:55:58] Downloading epp.package.java.executable.win32.win32.x86_64
[2017-02-12 11:55:58] Collected 1 artifacts for http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/neon in 0.219s
[2017-02-12 11:55:58] An error was detected while performing the engine operation and the changes are being rolled back. See the log for details.
[2017-02-12 11:55:58] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=4 An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:280)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:547)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3305)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3214)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3114)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1271)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$31(SimpleVariablePage.java:1148)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1093)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 session context was:(profile=C__Users_Kai_eclipse_java-neon2_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine code=0 Error reading signed content.
  java.io.IOException: Exception in opening zip file: C:\Users\Kai\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.aether.api_1.0.1.v20141111.jar
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3305)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3114)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$31(SimpleVariablePage.java:1148)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage$20.run(SimpleVariablePage.java:1093)
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Kai\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.aether.api_1.0.1.v20141111.jar (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.getZipFile(SecureAction.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.signedcontent.SignedBundleHook.getSignedContent(SignedBundleHook.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.checkCertificates(CertificateChecker.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CertificateChecker.start(CertificateChecker.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust.completePhase(CheckTrust.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.postPerform(Phase.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Phase.perform(Phase.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.PhaseSet.perform(PhaseSet.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.Engine.perform(Engine.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director.PlanExecutionHelper.executePlan(PlanExecutionHelper.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$3.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:729)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3305)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3233)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3114)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.installPerform(SimpleVariablePage.java:1271)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SimpleVariablePage.access$31(SimpleVariablePage.java:1148)
    ... 1 more
```

[2017-02-12 11:55:58]

I didn't notice anything wrong. I have no idea what's going on. I would like to know how to fix these issues and if nothing works if there are IDEs similar to Eclipse that I could use.  Thank you!

Comment: Also you should use the oomph installer. It checks a bunch of stuff for you

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Andreas I had 4 neon eclipse for diffrent project .

Comment: i was trying to install another eclipse and got above error , as solution tried deteting the .p2 file. Now not able to open other 4 installed eclipse and also not able to install new eclipse